# applepushserviced and ocspd takes a lot of memory, is killing them safe?

Tags: macos

I'm in my office and the the network access is limited, would this causing this two process taking too much memory?
I use my Mac mainly for developing, would it be safe to kill this two process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS handles unneeded processes automatically by swapping them out to disk while they are not running. You won't get significant amounts of memory back by killing them.

In addition at least `ocspd` is started automatically by OS X if needed. So even if you kill it, it will be started again as soon as Safari (or any other app) needs to verify certificates.

Comment: would 700+MB real memory and 1.5GB virtual memory be OK for applepushserviced? I'm not sure if that name is real memory since I'm not using an English system.

Comment: Size doesn't matter, it's swapped out as long as it doesn't run. And I have about the same numbers here.

Comment: OK, Thanks, maybe it's the swap with cause my mac slow down.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Activity Monitor and keeping an eye on CPU cycles to see what's chewing up RAM, which is a big slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

I regularly need to kill applepushserviced. *I am guessing about why that process goes bad every few days, but I am within a corporate firewall and forced to use draconian proxies.* It drives that process crazy for some reason. I am on 10.7.4...

Any way, I just came into work, and upon waking my machine, it was immediately bogged down. But I had Activity monitor open. All 8 cores were maxed out and I saw applepushserviced using over 10 Gigs (!) of real mem. **Killing that process** was a pleasure with instant results. Things were normal right away.

Of course that process starts right back up, so I'll need to create a launchd file to run an occasional kill command on it.